# How do I retrieve data sent to the web server in ASP.NET?

Tags: html, asp.net

What are the ways to retrieve data submitted to the web server from a form in the client HTML in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also search through both the Form and QueryString collections at the same time so that the data will be found regardless of the the request method.

```
value = Request("formElementID")
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET

For POST requests:

```
value = Request.Form("formElementID")
```

For GET requests:

```
value = Request.QueryString("formElementID")
```